# What is the difference between the object serialization and Filewriter?

Tags: java, serialization, filewriter

I am going through Head first Java,and I have reached Serialization Topic,It states that if If your data will be used by only the Java,program that generated it then use serialization or else If your data will be used by other programs then write to a plain text file.

But i have read that the serialization of an object is JVM independent.
Also when we serialize an object,the its data gets saved but when we use the FileWriter and fileReader then what we print gets stored in the file,different from the serialization right?

Also when is a bufferedreader used,how do we use it in cse with filewriter.

Comment: 3 different (and frankly *unrelated*) questions. Try googling each *individually* :)

Comment: Serializing objects creates files that can only be deserialized by the program or at least one that has the same dependency of the serialized objects. Writing to plain text or xml or json, you can read in data with whatever you want. You can import it into a db or make it even human-readable.

Comment: I did but i was confused,that is why I asked here,still thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is one (of various) concepts that describes how to do achieve **persistence** for your Java objects. Basically the term refers to a protocol that is used to turn any object into a stream of bits and bytes.

What you **do** with that stream of bits and bytes very much depends ... on well; what you want do with it.

A FileWriter on the other hand; is a completely unrelated "concept" - basically it is part of the IO framework that Java offers you to resolve tasks like "reading or writing something from/to the file system".

In other words: you can use serialization to turn Java objects into bits and bytes. You can use a FileWriter; or one of its many specific subclasses to get those bits and bytes ... from memory into a file that lives on your disc.

For the other parts of the your question - I wholeheartedly recommend you to **study** the many many online resources yourself. The intention of this site is to **help** with programming problems; not to **teach** you things that you can find in zillions of books or web sites.

To address your comments: if you are dealing with a Java object, you can call its methods. If you are dealing with raw bits and bytes ... basically you can only write those somewhere; or read them from somewhere. And you can take the bytes, and re-constitute a Java object from them. On which you can call methods again. It is like taking your money to your bank account: when you "persist" your money, just the information about the numbers is stored somewhere (but nobody keeps **your** coins and bills in **your** account). You can come back later on, the information is looked up; and you receive new coins when doing a withdrawal. Maybe that helps ..

Comment: I have just started with java,i did google these three in seperate searches,and it was still confusing to me ,i just wanted to ask why do we use bufferedreader when its not necessary,but i googled that and got the answers,thank you for your reply

Comment: The reason i am confused is i guess i don't understand the what does objects in bytes mean,like what good does it happen when it gets into bytes and whats are we limited to when it is not in bytes.
Again i am just a beginner,it may sound dumb,but please do help.